# Is it possible to include div contents in a java script mailto

Tags: javascript, html, css, mailto

I want to add a div to a mail to, is that possible? I have got all the mail to code but just need to know if i can include a div.

```js
function sendit(argument) {
  window.location.href = "mailto:" + "" + "?subject=" + "Hello";


}
```

```html
<button id="mailresults" class="button" onclick="sendit()">Mail Results</button>
<p>
  <div id="hidegameinfo">
    <div id="headerintro">
      Goals:</div>
    <div id="goalsstyle">
      <span id="goals">0  -  0</span>
    </div>
    <div id="headerintro">
      Corners:</div>
    <p>

      <span id="corners">0  -  0</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for your help.